# Distinct count of users with net balance > 0

Tags: powerbi, dax

My data looks like this.

[image: data and expected result]

I tried with below DAX but I am getting an error:

```
Distinct Users = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(MyList[User]),SUM(MyList[Balance]) > 0)
```

> Error message: A function 'SUM' has been used in a True/False
>   expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not
>   allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by using a calculated column to evaluate the balance and then use that to calculate the measure:

**Column:**

```
Distinct Users Test = 
        VAR User = MyList[User]    
RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(MyList[Balance]),
                FILTER(MyList,MyList[User]=User))
```

**Measure:**

```
Distinct Users = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(MyList[User]),
                            MyList[Distinct Users Test]>0)
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: If you want it as a single measure, You can make use of summarize and calculatetable:

```
Distinct Users New = COUNTX(
                            CALCULATETABLE(SUMMARIZE(MyList,MyList[User],
                                            "Bal",
                                            SUM(MyList[Balance]))),
                            [Bal]>0)
```

Comment: It works. but is there any way doing it without creating the calculated column?

Comment: Hmm.. Getting below error.

The function COUNTX cannot work with values of type Boolean.

Comment: You are creating it as a column, the calculation is a measure